# How i show the Custom field name in _loginpartial.chtml file in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How i replace the

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
<text>
    Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
    @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
    }
</text>
```

} else {

```
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
</ul>
```

}

with my Firstname that are store in userprofile table in mvc 4

Answer (score 0):

You would need to replace `User.Identity.Name` with `Model.Firstname` assuming that you have access to a model with the firstname in it.

Comment: Please tell me how i access the model in _loginpartial-chtml file

Comment: i am using @model ScoreMyOffer.Domain.ViewModels.ManageUserProfileViewModel but this is not working

Comment: i am add @Model=>Model.FirstName but it show the "External component has thrown an exception."

Comment: what happens if you just do Model.FirstName?

Comment: It would probably be easier, if you included all of your code in the original question as well!

Comment: Hello, @Html.ActionLink(Model.FirstName, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!

Comment: @model ScoreMyOffer.Web.Controllers.AccountController

Comment: Are you passing that model through to the page in the first place?

Where _loginpartial is called, is that model being passed through to it? so like this for example:

@Html.Partial("_loginpartial", Model) where the Model has already been created.

Comment: so what i add in the top

Comment: Please edit your question and provide all of the code for _loginpartial and all of the code for where that is being called from. Otherwise it's impossible to have a good idea of what you are doing wrong.